# Getting rid of link-click "flash" indicator in iOs UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, ios

My iPad app uses a lot of UIWeb views to display content. The user clicks small images with links to pull up a smaller view with additional content. When you tap a link in a UIWebview, the link highlights gray for a moment to indicate the click. In the case of links in an in an image, the whole image rectangle flashes gray for a moment, and it's pretty ugly. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sure, use the -webkit-tap-highlight-color CSS property:

```
  <style type="text/css">
  a {
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }       
  </style>
```

Comment: Wow awesome, thanks. For some reason I thought that was some hard-coded iPad thing that was going to be a pain to deal with. Silly me.