# UIWebView link tap highlight gray box shows up in wrong place or wrong size/shape

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a number of image links in my UIWebView, and they show a gray highlight box when they're tapped.  That's fine, but the box is either in the wrong place (too low relative to the image - starts about halfway down the image and extends below it) or the wrong size/shape (smaller than the image).

My images have widths and heights defined, but they seem ignored by the highlight. As far as I can tell I'm not doing anything fancy with my CSS.

For now I'm just going to disable it using this:

[Getting rid of link-click "flash" indicator in iOs UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772477/getting-rid-of-link-click-flash-indicator-in-ios-uiwebview)

But the highlight doesn't actually bother me, and the feedback is nice - any ideas how I can get it to actually match the images?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this? I am having similar issues.